# React don't render answer

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, babeljs

Thanks for visiting my question.
I am making a simple calculator via react.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.2/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/15.6.2/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Task 4</title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react-dom.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.38/browser.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
<div id="calculator"/>
<script type="text/babel">
    var Calculate=React.createClass({
        getInitialState:function(){
            return{
                 firstvalue: 0, secondvalue: 0, operation : "+", answer: 0
                 }
        },
        handleFirstValueChange(event)
        {
            var localvalue=event.target.value.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim()
            this.setState({
                firstvalue:localvalue
            });
            this.Answer()
        },
        handleSecondValueChange(event)
        {
            var localvalue=event.target.value.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim()
            this.setState({
                secondvalue:localvalue
            })
            this.Answer()
        },
        handleSum(event)
        {
            this.setState({
                operation:"+",
            })
            this.Answer()
        },
        handleSub(event)
        {
            this.setState({
                operation:"-"
            })
            this.Answer()
        },
        handleMul(event)
        {
            this.setState({
                operation:"*"
            })
            this.Answer()
        },
        handleDiv(event)
        {
            this.setState({
                operation:"/"
            })
            this.Answer()
        },
        Answer()
        { 
            switch(this.state.operation)
            {
                case "+" :
                this.setState({
                    answer:Number(this.state.firstvalue)+Number(this.state.secondvalue)
                    })
                    break; 
                case "-" :
                this.setState({
                    answer:Number(this.state.firstvalue)-Number(this.state.secondvalue)
                    }) 
                    break;
                case "*" :
                this.setState({
                    answer:Number(this.state.firstvalue)*Number(this.state.secondvalue)
                    })
                    break;
                case "/":
                this.setState({
                    answer:Number(this.state.firstvalue)/Number(this.state.secondvalue)
                    }) 
                    break;
            }
        },
        render:function(){
            return(
            <div>
            <input type="text" className="search-field" onChange={this.handleFirstValueChange}/>
            <input type="text" className="search-field" onChange={this.handleSecondValueChange}/>
            <div/>
            <button onClick={this.handleSum}>
            Сложить
            </button>
            <button onClick={this.handleSub}>
            Вычесть
            </button>
            <button onClick={this.handleMul}>
            Умножить
            </button>
            <button onClick={this.handleDiv}>
            Поделить
            </button>

            <div>{this.state.firstvalue} {this.state.operation} {this.state.secondvalue} ={this.state.answer} </div>
            </div>
            )}
    });
    ReactDOM.render(
             <Calculate/>,
             document.getElementById("calculator")
         );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to render an answer when I edit the first or second field. But it renders only after the press button or editing field again. I don't see how to fix, I think it can be with render, but I am called an Answer() function on these 2 fields and it does not give me a result. I am trying to link Answer() with the event in render but it did not give success. 
Thanks a lot.
First 2 scr it's stackoverflow.
I want this result. Edit field, or button and give answer immediately.

Comment: I think you would have got more responses if you had posted a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt. Right now this is too much code to review and provide any help.

Comment: `this.state` is NOT mutated when calling `this.setState()` - you can calculate `answer` from render as a normal variable, or use `this.Answer(localvalue)` instead of reading the previous state from `this.state`

Answer (score 0):

this.state is NOT mutated when calling this.setState() - you can calculate answer from render as a normal variable, or use this.Answer(localvalue) instead of reading the previous state from this.state – Aprillion 30 mins ago
Thanks a lot.
I am add
const Answer= this.Answer();
in render